# Create a variable which is: the order of a variable, within a categorical variable

Tags: r, sorting

I have data like this:

```
Colour Length
Blue     1
Blue     2
Blue     4
Red      6
Red      1
Red      2
Green    4
Green    1
Green    6
```

I'd like to create a third column which is the order of values in length, within each colour. So it should look like this:

```
Colour Length  Order
Blue     1       1
Blue     2       2
Blue     4       3
Red      6       3
Red      1       1
Red      2       2
Green    4       2
Green    1       1
Green    6       3
```

THANKS very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base` R you can use `ave` with the `rank` function:

```
df$Order<-ave(df$Length,df$Colour,FUN=rank)
#  Colour Length Order
#1   Blue      1     1
#2   Blue      2     2
#3   Blue      4     3
#4    Red      6     3
#5    Red      1     1
#6    Red      2     2
#7  Green      4     2
#8  Green      1     1
#9  Green      6     3
```

Comment: I've used this to find group means, medians, max. I'd like to use it to find different percentiles too but can't find a list of functions that will work here. Would you know how to do this? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `order` the 'Length' grouped by 'Colour', we get the sequence of rows and assign (`:=`) it to a new column 'Order'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Length), Order := seq_len(.N) , by = Colour]
df
#    Colour Length Order
#1:   Blue      1     1
#2:   Blue      2     2
#3:   Blue      4     3
#4:    Red      6     3
#5:    Red      1     1
#6:    Red      2     2
#7:  Green      4     2
#8:  Green      1     1
#9:  Green      6     3
```